# how to control the size of swt tooltip?

Tags: java, swt

Hi I am trying to use swt tooltip on my control But I see the it comes in bigger size which looks odd on controls Like beI see calling settooltiptext gives the tooltip on exact size of the text.Is there any way to achieve the same .

Sample Code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolTip;

public class TextFieldTooltip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
        final ToolTip tip = new ToolTip(shell, SWT.BALLOON);
        tip.setMessage("tooltip");

        Text tfTooltip = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        tfTooltip.setText("sample text field");
        tfTooltip.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                tip.setVisible(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                Text actionWidget = (Text) e.widget;
                Point loc = actionWidget.toDisplay(actionWidget.getLocation());
                tip.setLocation(loc.x + actionWidget.getSize().x - actionWidget.getBorderWidth(), loc.y);
                tip.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        Text tfNext = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        tfNext.setText("TF withdeafult");
        tfNext.setToolTipText("Default tooltip");
        shell.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

I prefer the ballon type tool tip to come in small popup w.r.t text  instead of that big .Any clue on this will be helpful

Comment: `ToolTip` doesn't seem to support any customization - but it is open source so you could always try creating a modified version of it. `setToolTipText` also doesn't support any customization.

Comment: Ohk thanks I was just needing pointers if the size can be modified .to contian only text before extending the class and write a custom one